# Jena SPARQL Query Execution stuck

Tags: sparql, jena, virtuoso

I am running the Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint for executing the query. but while I am executing the query my execution stuck.

```
QueryExecution qexec = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("now inside");
        String queryString = "PREFIX  ns:  <http://example.org/ns#>" +
                "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>\r\n" + 
                "SELECT  ?title ?price" + 
                "  {" + 
                "    ?x ns:price ?p ." + 
                "    ?x ns:discount ?discount ." + 
                "    ?x <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title> ?title . " + 
                "    BIND ('12'^^xsd:integer AS ?price)" + 
                "    FILTER( ?price < 20 )" + 
                "  }";
        System.out.println(queryString);
        System.out.println("inside the sparql just before call");
        qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://192.168.99.100:8890/sparql", queryString);

        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
        System.out.println("inside the sparql just after call");
        // write to a ByteArrayOutputStream
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ResultSetFormatter.outputAsJSON(outputStream, results);

        String json = outputStream.toString();
        System.out.println(json);

        return json;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        qexec.close();
    }
    return "Error";
```

**sample data**

```
@prefix dc:   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix :     <http://example.org/book/> .
@prefix ns:   <http://example.org/ns#> .

:book1  dc:title     "SPARQL Tutorial" .
:book1  ns:price     42 .
:book1  ns:discount  0.2 .

:book2  dc:title     "The Semantic Web" .
:book2  ns:price     23 .
:book2  ns:discount  0.25 .
```

While executing `qexec.execSelect()` it shouldn't give any error nor output result. But it will happen occasionally.

As while tracing it will print all the details up to below statement

```
System.out.println("inside the sparql just before call");
```

but not after that.

How do I trace it? How do I figure out what causes the issue?

Note: My query is very small so there is no time issue.

Also, I notice that after updating the new updated version of Jena 3.7.0 I am getting this issue

Comment: Nobody knows your data nor your query ... that's not helpful! And does it mean the query sometimes works? Please show the query?

Comment: @AKSW I have updated the details. Yes after restart the tomcat server query run 2 times but after that, it got stuck as i said in question

Comment: Now it's the first time that you mention the Tomcat server ... do you close the query execution object each time?

Comment: @AKSW yes every time close the query execution using qexec.close(); method

Comment: If it didn't print "after query" the code didn't get there so was there an exception in the Tomcat logs? (and that means qexec.close was not closed - use Java try-resource.)

Comment: @AndyS please see an updated question I have added the whole program. not getting any exception. Also as I pointed out in an early comment it will run for two times perfectly after that it got stuck.

Comment: "exactly two times"? that must be some issue with Tomcat, I don't see how Jena should be the problem. the only thing might be that you'Re flooding the local triple store with requests (high number of queries in a very short time, usually happing with some code/Scrips) - but again, nobody knows what you're doing in general, thus, it'S hard to give any further advice. As Andy said, check the Tomcat logs, maybe you can see something there.

Comment: You also said, that it happens after updating the Jena version. Are you sure that it worked before? IIRC, you used an ancient version 2.8.x or something

Comment: Check the Virtuoso logs as well. How many queries are received?

Comment: If I read the current version of the question correctly, all was working as expected until you updated Jena? That suggests the issue lies in Jena, since that's the thing that changed! Though I wonder — are you using the latest [Jena Provider and JDBC Driver](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSDownload#Jena%20Provider) for Virtuoso, and did you update the Jena Provider to match your new Jena version?

Comment: The OP is not using the OpenLink client side code - it is HTTP access created by `QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService`. The exact problem is changing though - it is now "it will happen occasionally."

Comment: "error [or] output result … will happen occasionally" -- What is the text of the occasional error?  You said tracing gets output `up to "before query"` -- but there is no `"before query"` in your code?  What does the trace show?  So much missing info!

Comment: @TallTed "What does the trace show?" for that, I have updated the question now you will understand.

Comment: @AKSW "Are you sure that it worked before?" for that, Yes it will not be stuck like this. After updating the Jena but the problem is I can't use "BIND" query in 2.8.8 version so that I have updated the version as you suggested.

Comment: Which means that there is a difference in the query then as well...that's again another information you missed to mention here. In addition, you can use `BIND` in older versions of Jena: `QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://192.168.99.100:8890/sparql", QueryFactory.create(queryString, Syntax.syntaxSPARQL_11))`

Comment: But still, I don't see why it should be stuck after **exactly 2 executions**. How do you perform the queries multiple times?

Comment: After changing this statement `QueryEngineHTTP  qexec = new QueryEngineHTTP ("http://192.168.99.100:8890/sparql", queryString);` it is working fine now. Thanks all @AKSW,@TallTed and @AndyS for your time.

Comment: That does a pure HTTP request then without parsing of the query itself. I still don't get why `QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService` doesn't work. Maybe @AndyS has an idea

Comment: It does not account for the "sometimes" effect so maybe an environmentally factor such as the OS and sockets reuse.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the comments correctly, I think that the issue was resolved by changing --

```
qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://192.168.99.100:8890/sparql", queryString);
```

-- to --

```
QueryEngineHTTP qexec = new QueryEngineHTTP ("http://192.168.99.100:8890/sparql", queryString);
```

-- which is a workaround that doesn't reveal the cause of the original problem, but nonetheless got past it successfully.